# What is the fastest way to "vectorize" a large number of matrix operations in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Say I want to do a lot of matrix multiplications in Numpy; what is the fastest way?

For concreteness, say this is the problem:  I have two long lists of matrices, and I want to elementwise multiply them together.  That is, I have

```py
[a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_N]
```

and

```py
[b_1, b_2, b_3, ..., b_N],
```

where each `a_i`, `b_i` is an `nxn` matrix (`n` is small, say `n=2`), and `N` is large (say `N = 100000`), and I want to find the matrix products `a_1 * b_1, a_2 * b_2, ...`

What is the fastest way to do this using Python and Numpy/Scipy?

some options are:

1. with a `for` loop--this is slow since Python loops are slow.
2. putting the small matrices into two `NxN` block diagonal matrices `A` and `B`--this will result in having to multiply a much bigger matrix than needed.
3. using `vectorize`-- this is easiest to code, but isn't any faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: Have you looked into `np.vectorize`?

Comment: @PranavVempati vectorize doesn't speed things up, it is the same speed as writing a for loop yourself.

Comment: @PranavVempati `np.vectorize` is basically a Python loop

Comment: "vectorize" in the `numpy` speedup sense really means replace python level loops with loops in compiled code, usually by using existing `numpy` methods.  The answers use the "batch" ability of `matmul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already can multiply 3D arrays, simply put your list of arrays into numpy arrays, e.g.,

```py
A = np.array([a_1, a_2, ..., a_N])
B = np.array([b_1, b_2, ..., b_N])
```

Then multiply `A @ B` (`@` is the matrix multiplication operator). Here's an example using two "lists" of 3x3 arrays:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.random.randint(0, 9, (2, 3, 3))

In [3]: y = np.random.randint(0, 9, (2, 3, 3))

In [4]: x
Out[4]:
array([[[0, 4, 8],
        [2, 5, 5],
        [3, 0, 5]],

       [[7, 6, 1],
        [7, 0, 7],
        [5, 2, 8]]])

In [5]: y
Out[5]:
array([[[7, 2, 6],
        [6, 1, 4],
        [6, 8, 5]],

       [[8, 5, 4],
        [8, 2, 7],
        [3, 7, 0]]])

In [7]: x @ y
Out[7]:
array([[[ 72,  68,  56],
        [ 74,  49,  57],
        [ 51,  46,  43]],

       [[107,  54,  70],
        [ 77,  84,  28],
        [ 80,  85,  34]]])
```

To demonstrate that all this does is the product of each matrix at the corresponding index:

```py
In [8]: x[0]
Out[8]:
array([[0, 4, 8],
       [2, 5, 5],
       [3, 0, 5]])

In [9]: y[0]
Out[9]:
array([[7, 2, 6],
       [6, 1, 4],
       [6, 8, 5]])

In [10]: x[0] @ y[0]
Out[10]:
array([[72, 68, 56],
       [74, 49, 57],
       [51, 46, 43]])

In [11]: (x @ y)[0]
Out[11]:
array([[72, 68, 56],
       [74, 49, 57],
       [51, 46, 43]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `numpy.matmul` or `@` like usual, it's a ufunc and can do broadcasting, just not on array elements but matrix subarrays. In your case, you just need to stack your (n,m) matrices in a (N,n,m) numpy array and your (m,p) matrices in a (N,m,p) numpy array.

```
m = np.array([[1, 3], [2,4]])

m
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])

m @ m
Out[13]: 
array([[ 7, 15],
       [10, 22]])

stackedm = np.stack([m,m,m])

stackedm
Out[15]: 
array([[[1, 3],
        [2, 4]],

       [[1, 3],
        [2, 4]],

       [[1, 3],
        [2, 4]]])

stackedm @ stackedm
Out[16]: 
array([[[ 7, 15],
        [10, 22]],

       [[ 7, 15],
        [10, 22]],

       [[ 7, 15],
        [10, 22]]])
```