# What is the fastest way to calculate a matrix product of vectors built element-wise?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I have the following MATLAB code to calculate the strain energy. I want to optimize this code, because this is where most of my time in an optimization problem is spent.

```
 stiffness = [6 x 6 matrix] % For a MWE, try magic(6)+magic(6)';
 exx(:)=[100 x 100 matrix]; eyy(:)=[100 x 100 matrix]; %etc.

 for idr = 1:length(r) % Index of r-location
     for idt = 1:length(theta) % Index of theta location
         e = [exx(idr,idt);eyy(idr,idt);ezz(idr,idt);2*exz(idr,idt);2*eyz(idr,idt);2*exy(idr,idt)]; % strain vector
         E(idr,idt) = e'*stiffness*e; %$ Strain energy at this location
     end
 end
```

There are two problems here:

- Since `length(r)==length(theta)==100`, this piece of code gets called 10k times.
- About a third of the time spent in the loop is on assembling `e` without actually doing any calculation.

I think there should be some ways to speed this up significantly by properly using vectorization, but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed in this particular case.

Note: there are some similar questions, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124927/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-vectorize-a-large-number-of-matrix-operations-in-nu), so perhaps there are some ideas that can be translated to MATLAB.

Comment: What are `exx`, `eyy`, etc? Please read [mre].

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry, those indeed got lost in some edits before posting the question. Will fix

Answer (score 2):

Another option, faster by about a factor ~x2 than @bla's answer,

```
eall=([exx(:),eyy(:),ezz(:),2*exz(:),2*eyz(:),2*exy(:)]);
E = reshape(sum(stiffness*eall.*eall),[100 100])
```

taking advantage of the fact that `e` is a vector so we can do the sum of element-wise multiplication instead of the vector product.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of vectorizing your code, doing the `vector'*matrix*vector` operation on all elements at once by extending the info to the 3rd dimension:

```
eall=([exx(:),eyy(:),ezz(:),2*exz(:),2*eyz(:),2*exy(:)]);
E=(reshape(pagemtimes(permute(eall,[3 2 1]),pagemtimes(stiffness,permute(eall,[2 3 1]))),[100 100]));
```

I'm not sure how significant will be the increase of performance, I get ~x5 on the 100x100 example you had...

Comment: Note: `pagemtimes` is introduced in 2020b.